# Permisson handler - location do not work (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, gps

I have a problem with Permisson Handler while try to use location.

When i tap and run gps func everything seems fine. Pop up is showing up I can choose options - Allow, Allow while Using etc, however when I choose allow or allow while it do not turn on location. It was working perfectly and just stopped somehow (permission is set to granted).

When I turn it on manually (Location on my device) everything is like it was before. I don't now why this prompt stops turning on location service.

```dart
void _onGpsTap() async {
    bloc.emitEvent(DisplayProgressIndicator());
    try {
      permissionStatus = await Permission.location.status;
      if (permissionStatus.isUndetermined) {
        permissionStatus = await Permission.location.request(); // Here I'm asking for turning location on
      }
      if (permissionStatus.isDenied) {...
```

I'm using

```
geolocator: ^5.3.1
permission_handler: 5.0.0+hotfix.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that is not possible to turn on location service via. flutter and the user have to do it maunally.

Answer (score 0):

**Try out below code:-**

```html
var status = await Permission.location.request();
    if(status.isGranted){
      log("Permission Granted");
      getAddress();
    }
```

```html
getAddress() async {
       Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
       latitude = position.latitude;
       longitude = position.longitude;
       if(latitude != null && longitude != null){
       apiCall();
       }
 }
```

`permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2`

`geolocator: ^7.2.0+1`

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use newer versions because of some requirements/dependencies in other packages. However, everything works fine. I mean geolocator works perfectly also permission statuses from the handler. Only issue is that after I select the option Always/While Using App it's not turning on location service and I had to do it manually.